# Insert Text atextfter a speficic class containing a spefiic word or phrase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I insert a Text after a speficic class containing a specific word or phrase?

Example:

```
<div class="TestBox">
    Hello World
</div>
```

Should be:

```
<div class="TestBox">
    Hello World it's me
</div>
```

I tried it to solve with a script, but the problem are:

1. The text (It's me) is duplicating
2. The text is out of the `div`

My Script:

```
$('<span>It's me</span>').insertAfter($("div:contains('Hello World')"));
```

Comment: what do you mean? are you trying to insert text into the div or after the div?

Comment: After the text would me perfect. Just as shown in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more inline with what you've tried!

## you need to use [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) instead of `append`

This basically, appends your span to each div the contains your class!

```js
$("<span>It's me</span>").appendTo($("div>:contains('Hello World')"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="TestBox">
    Hello World
</div>
```

Note:
With the example shares in comments,
On using `$("div:contains('erneut.')")` two divs are picked,
`[div.wrapper, div.plentyMessageBox]`

Therefore, use >:contains to pic the div containing the text!

`$("div>:contains('erneut.')")`
`[div.plentyMessageBox]`

Comment: Problem is, that is appers duplicate: Once inside the <div> and once outside of the <div>

Comment: Glad that it helped! once inside and once outside? I dont get it! Can you share the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) please!

Comment: I'm sorry. I still dont get it. what is meant when your say ' appears duplicate'?

Comment: The Text "It's me" appears once inside the <div>, right next to "Hello World" and again under the <div>. On fiddle it works fine. It seems there is problem with my page code :-(

Comment: oh may be. Look into your html structure!

Comment: Here is the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/oyL288ew/1/ As more parent div exists as more text is added after it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142231/discussion-between-browntoast-and-keerthana-prabhakaran).

Comment: I've added the edits! To get the element that has the text alone, you can use `div>:contains()`

Comment: It works fine on fiddle but on my page it has the same result: Its duplicating again

Comment: i've found my mistake :-) Thanks very much for your help Keerthana ;-) ;-)!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$( ".plentyMessageBox" ).append( "Your text" );
```

This would append "Your Text" to the div. If you want to make a comparison with the text, you could try to put a conditional like this:

```
if()$( ".plentyMessageBox" ).text()=="Hello World") {
    $(".plentyMessageBox" ).append( "Your text" );}
```

This is but one way of doing this, there are plenty.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using `append()`.

```js
$('.plentyMessageBox').append("<span>It's me</span>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plentyMessageBox">
    Hello World
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( ".plentyMessageBox" ).each(function() {
 if($(this).text() == "Hello World"){
  $(this).append("<span> it's me</span>");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plentyMessageBox">Hello World</div>
<div class="plentyMessageBox">Hello World it's me</div>
<div class="plentyMessageBox">Hello World NOT me</div>
```